# Swift 2.0 CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation

Tags: xcode, swift, cllocationmanager

After updating to xCode 7 beta and converting my code to the newest Swift Version, the method "startUpdatingLocation" does not work anymore. The Error says: "'startUpdatingLocation()' is unavailable"

Am I missing something?

```
self.locationManager.delegate = self
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 5

self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()  // Error here
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you made sure the app is allowed to access location with `class func authorizationStatus() -> CLAuthorizationStatus` ? If not, you should call `func requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`  or `func requestAlwaysAuthorization()`  and set the corresponding text in Info.plist (NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription, NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription)

Answer (score 1):

This call fails to compile because it's flagged with __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED.
As to why it fails to compile, I'm not up-to-speed on location issues for watchOS but it seems that continuous location tracking is not allowed on the watch itself.  WWDC 2015 Session 714 What's New in Core Location discusses this in depth (haven't yet had a chance to watch it myself, alas).

The watchOS developer library has a PotLoc sample which is sample code for using CoreLocation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/samplecode/PotLoc/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016176

In particular, use manager.requestLocation() and then implement the delegate method optional

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject])
```